# How can I copy Eclipse classpath variables from one workspace to a new workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

How can I copy the [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) classpath variables from the open workspace to a new workspace?  I am using [Eclipse Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/) (Eclipse Platform 4.2.1 and Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.8.2).

Comment: You mean the classpath that Eclipse is running with, or the classpath used for some run configuration of your own code?

Comment: Did you check this one? Maybe this one answers it for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733518/eclipse-copy-the-java-build-path-to-a-different-workspace

Comment: @sharakan: I mean the classpath variable definitions which the workspace stores and are shared or are global to all projects in that workspace.

Comment: @Amit: Yes, I saw that question, but it refers to the Java build path (classpath), not the classpath variables (names and values).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try File -> Export -> General -> Preferences and export All.  Next, import the preferences into your second workspace.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to work; the classpath variables stay the same after importing.

Answer (score 1):

Classpath variables are stored in *at least* three places in eclipse:

**Workspace level**

These are effectively global, and can be seen in Preferences->Java->Build Path->Classpath variables.  You could export these as with any other preferences, and import them to your new workspace.

**Project level**

Seen in the Project->Properties->Java Build Path editor.  These are stored in the .classpath file in the project root.  You could simply copy and paste relevant sections from one .classpath file to another if you want to avoid using the project properties editor.

**Run configuration**

These are classpath variables used to actually execute code from Eclipse, you can see them in Run->Run configurations->(select one)->Classpath tab.  You can 'save' a configuration by going to the 'Common' tab and changing it from 'local' to 'shared', and then move that shared file whereever you care to.

Comment: File `.classpath` can refer to the classpath variable names, but it doesn't store the value of classpath variables.  Only the workspace stores the classpath variables names and values.

Comment: In that case, the preferences export should do the job. Does it not?

Comment: Yes, unless there is a way to have Eclipse do these automatically when you ask it to create a new workspace.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do now...  AFAIK, there is no way to 'copy settings from' (or subset thereof) when creating a new workspace, which is kind of a shame.  Only other alternative I know of to exporting/importing prefs is actually copying the workspace/.metadata folder which contains the raw prefs.  This is iffy though, could contain paths that don't make sense in the new workspace among other potential hazards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no direct way to achieve this. I found a workaround solution.
Try the File System export, select only .classpath files for all the Projects you want to export and in the options select 'Create directory structure for files' to make sure each project classpath is generated in its own folder.

for using this to import, just copy-paste the exported files(containing only .classpath file) to the new workspace.